# Can you use green-flame blade on yourself to hit an oni in gaseous form?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can you use *green-flame blade* on yourself to hit an [oni](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/oni) in [*gaseous form*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gaseous-form)? The DM is saying that *green-flame blade* cannot touch a creature using gaseous form. I feel that this is ludicrous due to *green-flame blade* being magic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes, but no need

You do not even need to hit yourself, you can target the creature in *gaseous form*. There is nothing in the description of the spell that would prevent someone from targeting the subject. It only reduces nonmagical *damage* (note that it does not grant immunity), and provides no protection against nonmagical *attacks* themselves (or any attack, for that matter).